# Alert sound for incoming emails

Tags: audio, alert

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find it , Would you please guide me where I can find the default MAC Osx sound alert file for new email

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sounds are stored in HD -> System -> Library -> Sounds
[image]

Comment: Thank you , 
but I'm actually looking for the sound file itself

Comment: @Dxtr I've updated my answer with the correct one. Apologies, it's 2AM here.

Comment: @Dxtr don't forget to flag it as the answer to your question, it helps viewers and also myself!

Comment: @ David ok Done .